# Implied prior with relationship $y=\text{arccot}(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

I'm trying to solve an exercise, which I think I have almost managed to solve but not quite. Any help would be appreciated!

So, what we have is a vector which we obtain by norming the vector $\lambda=(x, 1)$, where $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$, into "half unit circle". I assume that this means that the vector we get is:

$$\lambda^*=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$

Expressed in terms of the polar coordinates, the vector is

$$
\lambda^*=(\cos y, \sin y)
$$
where $y\in[0,\pi)$. If $y$ is assigned the uniform prior, what is the implied prior for $x$? A hint is that $y=\text{arccot}x$.

My way of reasoning is this. First, the cdf of $y$ is
$$
F_Y(y)=\frac{y}{\pi}, \quad 0\leq y <\pi.
$$

Furthermore, we have the following relationship:
$$
\sin y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
which means

$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{\sin y}\\
x=\left(\frac{1}{\sin y}\right)^2-1
$$

Using the transformation theorem, we can obtain

$$
F_X(x)=Pr(X\leq x)=Pr\left(\frac{1}{(\sin Y)^2}-1\leq x\right)=Pr\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\leq(\sin Y)^2\right)
$$
This is where I think I go wrong. To continue and get $Y$ by itself, I need to take the square root and then the inverse of sin. But then I'll have $\sqrt{x+1}$, which will yield non-real numbers for $x<-1$ (remember that $x\in(-\infty, \infty)$.

Any ideas how to attack this?

Comment: Note that $x \mapsto y$ is not invertible. For any $y\ne \pi$, there are two values of $x$ mapping to that $y$. You'll need to use this fact in your application of the transformation theorem.

Comment: There is a problem of missing square root and a problem of undefined sign in your computations.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you! With that in place my calculations yield the same answer as you posted below, which I suspect I should get as it is a Cauchy distribution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One considers $Y$ uniform on the interval $(0,\pi)$ and $X=\cot Y$. There are several ways to compute the distribution of $X$, one is to start from the fact that $[X\leqslant x]=[Y\geqslant\cot^{-1} x]$ for every real number $x$, hence
$$
F_X(x)=1-\frac1\pi\cot^{-1}x,
$$
and, by differentiation,
$$
f_X(x)=\frac1\pi\frac1{1+x^2}.
$$

Comment: That's a very neat (and perhaps obvious) solution. I'm not completely following why $[X\leq x]=[Y\geq \cot^{-1} x]$ though. If I do it I get $Pr(X\leq x)=Pr(\cot Y \leq x)=Pr(Y \leq \cot^{-1} x)$, i.e. less than and not greater than or equal to as you got. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that $\cot$ is a decreasing function.